# objective c coding guidelines

Tags: iphone, objective-c, programming-languages, coding-style

Is there any pdf which tells about coding guidelines in objective C.

For Example...

```
 1. Breaking the function names - checkIfHitTheTrack. 
 2. member variables must be like - mVariableName.
 3. Giving better names to subclass - ?
```

Please share the related links...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would start with these:

1. Apple's [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html)
2. Google's [Objective-C Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/objcguide.xml)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Objective-C Beginner's Guide](http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html).