# Size already defined

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, objective-c++

I was messing with my Objective-C++ namespace today.

I found that Handle, Size and Duration are already defined in ObjC++. What are they defined to be and where are they defined?

I have only #imported Foundation/Foundation.h

Comment: Can you show us the list of includes that you've used?

Comment: listed imports as you requested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MacTypes.h

```
typedef char *                          Ptr;
typedef Ptr *                           Handle;
typedef long                            Size;
typedef SInt32                          Duration;
```

These all predate Carbon.  They having nothing to do with Cocoa even though they fill up the namespace.

Answer (score 2):

You can Command-double-click on a symbol in Xcode to see where it's defined, or use "Open Quickly" (Command-Shift-D) and type a symbol name.  `Handle`, `Size` and `Duration` are in the CoreServices framework, for example.

To avoid conflicts, you should always use a unique prefix (typically your initials or a shortened version of your project's name) in your global Objective-C names.  Take a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543090/) which link to some Objective-C style guides.